# Найти две цифры в строке и записать их в переменные.

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка вида "Oplata podpiski 1 mesjats ot polzovatelja 12"
Мне нужно после слова "podpiski" вытащить цифру и положить её в $order_id, а после "polzovatelja" положить в $user_id.
Дело в том что в LiqPay можно передать только Description, по этому нужно сделать это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$target = "Oplata podpiski 1 mesjats ot polzovatelja 12";

preg_match_all('~\d+~', $target, $matches);

list($order_id, $user_id) = $matches[0];
```

Отмечу, что "один месяц" все убьет. Лучше использовать четкую структуру данных (например, `[$order_id/$user_id] описание`).

Comment: Дело в том, что это будет на русском и при оплате через LiqPay в описании платежа будет видно это. Не сильно хочется, чтобы пользователь видел просто order_id и user_id. А понимал, за что платил. Всё же логируется. Я бы и сам так сделал, но.

Comment: @Александр Клюев ничто не мешает оставить описание (что я и сделал), находить ID пользователя через ID заказа, а сам ID заказа расположить в самом начале или хотя бы дать ему заранее известный префикс.